# Hyperledger-indy: Transaction has been rejected: client request invalid: InsufficientCorrectSignatures

Tags: hyperledger-indy

I'm learning hyperledger indy, and am facing a problem while adding a new node as a validating node using indy-cli. I have already created a wallet of name "user" with type "default" and use DID from one of STEWARD of domain_transaction_genesis, but I am facing an error while adding the new node as a validating node:

> pool(pool1):wallet(user1):did(V4S...e6f):indy> ledger node target=69M5KYGMA9nXyy W3ouWA1P8papeK4qHbXHndsvm24UYu client_port=9710 client_ip=127.0.0.1 alias=Node5  node_ip=127.0.0.1 node_port=9709 services=VALIDATOR blskey=4avkdyan8TgVTHxVoQJLR PFRkdfGfHbERk2YLCDUaRsnrAcZ9emdaWu89zwUdcUJtb4S2E754zZbMxGszkohc8Sqxg11skSvgymwR Knp2mRso7zecwrT7XHtD7BYwQC32LUbuvrfG2CpEtBLGcYcrcKpHbGhhNS6ZtzebyTggyzuwbg blske y_pop=RJg3byoYivJqKib1MMZzxHs8dDYxCcxLMGZyzoG9eXWiSoK8c1vRUphoDdiGYpQa1Z61rM2iQb wt7q5uZbLfke8p9jaQusWv3TkLvZsGdPuKp9W2v192URtXL4DyE9trEZF4oMQGe1CBukTHe8tHcj4r9G BSBXmBU6EjQ28fQfw4LP
>
> Error: Transaction has been rejected: client request invalid: InsufficientCorrectSignatures(0, 1)

Please help me properly perform a transaction on indy network. I'm following this documentations for guide:

https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/node/en/latest/add-node.html

Answer (score 2):

I had solved the same problem.
That error was because of **wrong VerKey parameter** used in the command assigning role to your node with 
      ledger nym did= .......... verkey=.......... role=STEWARD

There is another VerificationKey value as the output of init_indy_node command. You mustn't use this value.

The solution, clearing and re-creating your node so that you can get new did and verkey values.

Comment: Thanks @taner, I also solved this problem but by creating new did with seed. Before i was not using seed to generate keys that's why i was having signature authentication error.

Comment: I want to vote you for replaying but i don't have enough reputation yet but i will when i will have enough reputation.

Comment: Had a similar problem onboarding a new Steward using indy-sdk with nodejs. Setting role to 'STEWARD' in the buildNymRequest fixed it. Thanks @Taner for putting me on the right path.