Issue with TRUSTEE DID and Onboarding New Node
I'm trying to use a TRUSTEE DID to publish a new DID with the role of STEWARD, but I keep encountering the following error:
Transaction has been rejected: client request invalid: insufficient number of valid signatures, 1 is required but 0 valid and 1 invalid have been provided.

I've attached an image below showing the exact error message I receive when trying to set the TRUSTEE DID as active and publish the new STEWARD DID.

My final goal is to use this TRUSTEE DID to onboard a new node. However, when I attempt this, I also get an error about an invalid signature. Moreover, when I try onboarding a new node using an existing STEWARD, I encounter an error that states:
STEWARD already has a node.

What I am trying to achieve:

Use a TRUSTEE DID to onboard a new node.
Assign a new STEWARD DID (created from the TRUSTEE) to handle the new node.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using a different method to onboard the node, or do I need to configure the signatures somehow when using the TRUSTEE DID?

Is this an actual programming-related question?

I'm wondering why this wouldn't be. It is not opinion-based. I'm 99% sure the problem is how I am generating/managing the DIDs on Indy and how the nodes are connected to each other. But I don't know what's wrong. Also here there's a similar question, but not applicable to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649793/hyperledger-indy-transaction-has-been-rejected-client-request-invalid-insuffi

Cause you didn't attach any code and I only see an image of a terminal with commandlines?

That's how Indy works, via command lines, Indy-CLI. In this case that question I linked from 5 years ago should be closed too. The solution they proposed there didn't work for me though.

Since I can not see your ledger I can not confirm the issue, how did you add the UgCkF... DID ? Is it generated from the node's seed ? What are your AUTH_MAP rules did you change them ?
I add nodes like this (at usr/local/bin of docker container) (docker container needs to have the nodeport and clientport ports exposed for this to work):
it is important to specify SomeSeed so that you can use it on the indy-cli part, if you want to onboard an existing DID, you should put that seed on the SomeSeed part.
init_indy_keys --name NodeName --seed SomeSeed 

start_indy_node NodeName 0.0.0.0 nodeport 0.0.0.0 clientport

After this at indy-cli, in the node of the TRUSTEE:
did new seed=SomeSeed

did use TRUSTEEDID

ledger nym did=did_generated_from_did_new verkey=verkey_generated_from_did_new role=STEWARD

did use did_generated_from_did_new

ledger node alias=NodeName target=verification_key_generated_at_init_indy_keys node_ip=127.0.0.1 node_port=nodeport client_ip=127.0.0.1 client_port=clientport services=VALIDATOR blskey=blskey_generated_at_init_indy_keys blskey_pop=blskey_proof_of_posession_generated_at_init_indy_keys

the IP addresses should be the external IP of your server if you are connecting multiple different computers on differing networks. I use one docker container with multiple nodes for testing purposes. (6 nodes running on the same container) this is why my parameters are 127.0.0.1




I found the problem, I had 4 nodes, each one with its STEWARD, when I tried generate a 5th Steward from Node 2 using a TRUSTEE DID, it failed when publishing to the DLT as invalid signature. But when I did from the Node 1, it worked properly, I think the problem is that the TRUSTEE was registered in Node 1, so to create new STEWARDS it should sign from this node, not any other. Then I could onboard new nodes without problems.

I edited your answer to specify that in Indy-cli it has to be from the node of TRUSTEE the command to onboard a new node. When it's approved I'll accept it
